# Problem with python interactive in VSCode

Tags: python, jupyter, visual-studio-code, python-interactive

TEMPORAL WORKAROUND: https://www.reddit.com/r/vscode/comments/i45agt/cannot_type_code_into_python_interactive_console/

**EDIT**: this is a bug in new version of VSCode. There are also a few issues raised on github with the same problem. I will leave the question here, despite that it still gets minus points and got closed twice, as I was not able to find out any answer by googling, maybe it will help someone.

... Asking the same question once again, could you please tell me what details shall I add or how to specify the problem in better way, before you close it again in 10 minutes? I am desperate, can not work and have no one to ask, there is nothing on google with this issue....

So I am using VSCode and an interactive environment. By now everything worked just fine and I am not aware that something changed (I have not installed anything new, nor updated anything, so it might have been done somewhere in the background). Now the problem arises: I am able to run interactive, but only from the script with using cells `#%%` , however, the interactive window does not allow me to write anything into it directly into *Type code here and press shift-enter to run*. What is even more strange, yesterday it allowed me to write into this window some code and execute it and then suddenly it stopped working and I had to write code into the script again...

I am using VSCode Version: 1.51.1 and python 3.7.4 64-bit.

Comment: Could you PLEASE add a note what info shall I provide, before you close it again? Or where else shall I ask?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same issue - it seems to be a bug in VScode. The only thing that works is simply to close it and open it again, until they fix it - anoying as it is

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you know about any way of contacting them, so that they know about this bug ? I mean, if no one tells them, they maybe dont even know about it...

Comment: maybe you can raise an issue here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode @pikachu

Comment: Ah okay, I am not able to do this... I wish I had a class for programming at uni... Thanks anyway..

Comment: Actually you don't need much skill for it. You can use the link below, and just describe the problem like you described here. But you need a github account. Also you can see many issues, opened and closed, from the link. Maybe you can find your solution there.

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues

Comment: I have checked and it is reported a few times there already, so I will wait for update. Thanks for help! :)

Comment: @pikachu Be sure to upvote the issue, if not enough votes it might not be looked at/fixed.

Comment: @pikachu can you link to the reported issue ?

Comment: 2 which came as first ones, I am sure there are more. https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/110622  https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/110526  is upvoting just giving it "like" ?